# Mean and variance of poisson distribution with variable lambda from (0,3)

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

How can we find mean and variance in possion distribution where lambda itself is variable. I am new to probability distribution. As far as i know, mean and variance of possion distribution is always lambda. but in case Lambda itself is a random variable, how can we tackle this.

I have this problem :
On any day, the number of accidents on the highway has a Poisson
distribution with parameter Λ. The parameter Λ varies from day to
day and is itself a random variable. Find the mean and variance of the
number of accidents per day when Λ is uniformly distributed on (0, 3).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sry, I am new to MSE, didn't know about that.. I have edited question,  since its fairly new topic for me, I am trying to understand how can resolve this problem.